# How to replace data from dynamic <a href="...." /> hyperlinks in php?

Tags: php

I got blocks of div hyperlinks as string in $code. This is example of blocks found in $code:

```
         <div id="" class="thumbo">
            <a href="/spring/days/fridayDay12/989876/" /><img src="http://www.somesite.com/pics/pic12345.jpg&token=32453454645efgdgfdgdfgdfg"></a>

         </div>
```

i want to replace everything before 4th slash with ./doit.php.id= 
For example i want change this :

```
<div id="" class="thumbo">
                <a href="/spring/days/fridayDay12/989876/" /><img src="http://www.somesite.com/pics/pic12345.jpg&token=32453454645efgdgfdgdfgdfg"></a>

             </div>
```

to

```
<div id="" class="thumbo">
                <a href="./doit.php?id=989876" /><img src="http://www.somesite.com/pics/pic12345.jpg&token=32453454645efgdgfdgdfgdfg"></a>

             </div>
```

The problem is that data before last 4th slash is dynamic and wonder how i can replace them all with ./doit.php?id=?

Comment: You have a php file and want to have these things replaced, or do you read this in a php variable and you want to replace it there?

Comment: Thanks Rubens for reply . I have those blocks of div as one php variable $code and want to replace them all and print the $code out after replace all.

Comment: rubens i want to remove anything before 4th slash in href but dont know how to use preg match all to do the replacement